# Nginx not displaying CSS, PNG & SVG

Tags: nginx, cache, gzip, css

I have been looking through the hundreds of questions about this for a couple of hours now, but I haven't been able to find a single one that's the exact same as mine.
Up until a week ago, all sites I've been serving on my server worked perfectly, but recently I noticed that most of my pages aren't being styled correctly, and some images aren't being displayed. I've enabled and disabled all gzip settings, and most other settings in nginx.conf. I've checked my logs, and all requests get the 200 code.

One of the websites on the server: http://dev.mcpartyhard.net (/favicon.png gets displayed in text for me)

Access.log, etc: http://pastebin.com/e81kAZpb

I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: For future reference - please put the _relevant_ config/info in the question - don't link offsite to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

```
more_set_headers "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8";
```

You are set header `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` for all responses

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be something stupid I was missing. That'll teach me for copy-pasting configs that work somewhere else.